# How do I remove mothball smell from metal?

Tags: smell

I recently got a metal tray full of nuts, bolts, washers, and drill bits from a yard sale, and it smells like mothballs. I know mothball off-gas is carcinogenic, so I wanted to reasonably decontaminate them before bringing them into my home. My current plan is just to spread them out outside and have a fan blowing at them until the smell dissipates.

Google seems to incorrectly suggest using a vinegar solution to remove the smell, but I believe that would cause corrosion on the metal so I'm hesitant.

Would airing them out be sufficient? Or is there any mechanism by which mothball smell/residue would continue to remain carcinogenic until washed off?

Comment: send them through the dishwasher, they do a great job of removing grease from flat metal things.

Answer (score 1):

The fan outside might work for the smell, but it still might leave undesirable chemicals on the surface.

I would use a good degreaser on them (dish soap is quite effective), but I would do it outside and while wearing gloves (and a respirator if you are concerned). After it is cleaned, you'll want to rinse and dry them to slow surface rust. If the smell is gone, a small amount of oil could then be used to prevent surface rust.

Comment: WD-40 is _precisely_ the correct "oil" to use for this. "Water Displacement, formula 40" was developed for the military to protect metal from rust.

Answer (score 0):

I would get a big plastic bucket with a lid - those ones for paint for example.

Then a couple of litres of water with vinegar or diesel and a handful of sand. Roll that around the garden a few times then drain, rinse ans treat with a light coating of wd40.